# check strings of a list

Tags: python, list

I want to when I input a string, if words in string is contain in a list of words, delete words in the strings

Comment: Please don't overwrite the built-in `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could do the following:

```
raw_string = input("Enter String:")
useless_list = ["Birds", "Cat"]
print(' '.join([i for i in raw_string.split() if i not in useless_list]))
```

Comment: How I can delete words in raw_string if useless_list contains any words of raw_string to delete the occurences ?

Comment: edit my new code up